# Join all columns to Lookup table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

main table `products` has over 10 columns , values in all columns should reference to `Lookup` table.

I added relation like below , but I think it's kind of weird! isn't it ?
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do ? From my short work experience, almost everytime something feels weird it's because of poor design.

Comment: Wow, I wonder if you could get some more lines drawn between those tables

Comment: @AaronBertrand , I didn't event press `CTRL+S`.

Comment: You should probably have a number of _separate_ lookup tables, especially as not all of those things will have parents.  
'VGA' implies a certain type of monitor adapter/resolution range, and is in the process of being phased out on newer graphics cards/monitors.  A better description of the problem domain would help us critique the design.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to reduce query performance. I hope your lookup table is in memory... If yes, this might be workable depending on the load of your system. Loop joins have very low latency for very few rows.

So if this is the properly normalized data model and you see no particular problems with it I think it is ok.